# How to display foursquare post-checkin screen in iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, foursquare

Adding the "foursquare check-in" ability to an existing app has raised some questions.  Mainly, "what to show after the user has checked in?".  Within the native foursquare client, after a checkin is completed, it will display a screen showing any badges, specials and points you earned with that checkin.

Since checking-in isn't the primary function of our app, we wanted a way to give the user an option to see this information on demand.  We can get all of this information from the API's checkin response, but we didn't want to reinvent the wheel.

We tried using the custom URL for displaying the native application as described here ([Client API](https://developer.foursquare.com/client/)) but that just displays the checkin information, not the results from it:`foursquare://checkins/CHECKIN_ID`

Is there a client URL that is undocumented that we can call to display this information, or will it need to be displayed in our app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no custom URL / intent for showing post check-in information. For now you'll need to reconstruct your version of the post check-in screen.

Comment: Thanks @akdotcom, my concern is with our users unlocking specials. Have you had any reports of venues not allowing specials unless they are in the native 4sq app?

Comment: A check-in is a check-in, doesn't matter what application the check-in originates from. That being said, we do monitor both official and external apps for suspicious behavior, abuse, etc.